# Spring Cloud Functions - Why does this work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm returning to Java after a loooong break and I've been playing around with Spring Cloud. The following code runs and returns a toll station when the retrieveStation() method is called.

***The problem is that I don't really understand how the method knows what stationId is when there's no input parameter.*** I'm somewhat familiar with functional programming in Java now but this seems a bit like magic to someone returning from the pre-JDK 8 days.

Anyone care to explain what's happening here or point me to a good tutorial? How does the stationId get injected into value? I've been Googling for an hour and can't find the answer. Thanks!

WebFunctionApplication.java

```
package demo.webfunction;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebFunctionApplication {

    List<TollStation> tollStations;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(WebFunctionApplication.class, args);
    }

    public WebFunctionApplication() {

        tollStations = new ArrayList<TollStation>();
        tollStations.add(new TollStation("100A", 112.5f, 2));
        tollStations.add(new TollStation("111C", 124f, 4));
        tollStations.add(new TollStation("112C", 126f, 2));

    }

    //A POST request with station Id to http://localhost:8080/retrieveStation will return values
    @Bean
    public Function<String, TollStation> retrieveStation() {

        return value -> {
            System.out.println("received a request for station - " + value);
            return tollStations.stream()
                    .filter(toll -> value.equals(toll.getStationId()))
                    .findAny()
                    .orElse(null);
        };
    }
}
```

TollStation.java

```
package demo.webfunction;

public class TollStation {

    private String stationId;
    private Float mileMarker;
    private Integer stallCount;

    public TollStation(String stationId, Float mileMarker, Integer stallCount) {
        this.stationId = stationId;
        this.mileMarker = mileMarker;
        this.stallCount = stallCount;
    }

    public String getStationId() {
        return stationId;
    }

    public void setStationId(String stationId) {
        this.stationId = stationId;
    }

    public Float getMileMarker() {
        return mileMarker;
    }

    public void setMileMarker(Float mileMarker) {
        this.mileMarker = mileMarker;
    }

    public Integer getStallCount() {
        return stallCount;
    }

    public void setStallCount(Integer stallCount) {
        this.stallCount = stallCount;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-function</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>web-function</name>
    <description>web-function</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-function-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[PostMan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY4fx.png)

Comment: what is printed `System.out.println("received a request for station - " + value);`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Whatever stationId I pass in via the POST. I added a picture of the PostMan output. It works fine. Just don't understand why.

Comment: Please confirm what happens when you post another value (existing and not existing)

Comment: Any stationId in the list will return the correct results. An empty POST will cause a 500 server error because the null value is unhandled.

Comment: It is magic, see https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-function/2.0.0.RELEASE/multi/multi__functional_bean_definitions.html

Comment: Also https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-function

Comment: Thanks for the links. Not sure that I understand completely but it sounds like Spring Cloud may be converting the methods with the @Bean annotation to a type that uses reflection to obtain the input value. I need to read more but this is a good start.

Comment: As posted by @DaveNewton
retrieveStation returns a lambda. It’s the lambda, called by Spring, that receives value as a parameter. That is retrieveStation’s signature: it returns a Function taking a String and returning a TollStation. The station ID isn’t available inside getStation, it’s passed to the function returned by getStation. docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/…

Comment: Ahh, I get it. So retrieveStation() isn't handling the POST at all. It's just returning a Function that can be used to extract the correct TollStation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The confusion was a result of me thinking the method was handling the HTTP POST somehow and not really have a great handle on functional programming in Java.  Thanks goes to @ScaryWombat.

This is how Spring Cloud must be using the method behind the scenes:

```
public class FunctionExample {

    List<TollStation> tollStations;

    public FunctionExample() {

        tollStations = new ArrayList<TollStation>();
        tollStations.add(new TollStation("100A", 112.5f, 2));
        tollStations.add(new TollStation("111C", 124f, 4));
        tollStations.add(new TollStation("112C", 126f, 2));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new FunctionExample().testRetrieveStation();
    }

    public void testRetrieveStation() {

        Function<String,TollStation> func = retrieveStation();

        TollStation station = func.apply("100A");
    }

    public Function<String, TollStation> retrieveStation() {

        return value -> {
            System.out.println("received a request for station - " + value);
            return tollStations.stream()
                    .filter(toll -> value.equals(toll.getStationId()))
                    .findAny()
                    .orElse(null);
        };
    }
}
```